# Database Table and Form Design

Tags: database-design

I have a database that tracks 5 parameters daily for each of 20 machines. Right now all of the data is all in one table which makes it really hard to pull out data for just machine 3 because I have 5 fields related to machine 3 and no way to combine all of the data to pull only the machine 3 data.

My form looks like a spreadsheet for entry with a label for each machine on the left side, and 5 parameters going to the right. I would like each machine to be one row of data in the database table, but I don't know how to tell each row that it is for a different machine without making the form users select each machine from a drop down in that row (record). The form is typically all filled out at the end of the shift, so I want to keep the data entry easy for them to see what they've entered and what is left.

Any ideas? should I make each row a subform with a default value in the machine field? TIA

Comment: Can you post the schema for your current table and the basic layout for what you are going for.  I think i have the general idea but want to make sure I'm thinking of your table correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your description it looks like you are going to need 2 tables: `Machines` and `Parameters`, having between them a 1-M relation.

[image: 1-Machine-to-many-Parameters]

The tables should look like this:

`Machines(id, name,...)`

`Parameters(id, param_type, value, time_of_reading, machine_id,...)`

Here is an example with data:

[image: MACHINES]    [image: PARAMETERS]

To get all the parameters of a single machine you would use:

Then to retrieve the latest value for one of your fields you run a query like:

```
    SELECT * FROM PARAMETERS 
    WHERE machine_id = 1 AND param_type='temperature' 
    ORDER BY time_of_reading DESC LIMIT 1
```

etc.

The syntax of the query may vary depending on the DBMS you are using.

When a new reading is submitted for each parameter value you do:

```
    INSERT INTO PARAMETERS (`param_type`, `value`, `time_of_reading`, `machine_id`)
      VALUES ('temperature', 189, DATE(NOW), 1)
```

etc.

The form could be a grid with each machine on each row and each parameter type in each column. Once the user submits the form then for each cell you should run a INSERT query like the one above.